# Populate List<String> in textarea from a Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, textarea, jstl

Hello I have this `List<String>` in a Servlet and I need to populate it to a textarea like

Servlet:
`List<String> some_words = null;
messages.put("property_name",some_words);`

JSP:

```
<textarea name="" id="">${messages.property_name}</textarea>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Well I just want the list of strings to populate in the textarea just like this: apple, banana, melon, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oYou can use [JSTL foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html) like this:

```
<textarea name="" id="">
  <c:forEach var="word" items="${some_words}">
    ${word},
  </c:forEach>
</textarea>
```

This would print it comma separated...

Don't forget you have to import the core JSTL library in your JSP with:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

EDIT: In order to pass through the list from the servlet to the JSP, you just have to store the list in the session and forward the request to the JSP with:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("some_words", some_words);
request.getRequestDispatcher("anotherPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Note that some_words is your list object and "some_words" is the name you give to it and the one you'll use in the JSP.

EDIT 2: In order to avoid print a comma after the last item you can user JSTL **if** and **varStatus**, so you can improve the last code like this:

```
<textarea name="" id="" varStatus="status">
  <c:forEach var="word" items="${some_words}">
    ${word}<c:if test="${!status.last}">, </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</textarea>
```

This way, in each loop, you check if the current item is the last one. Only if it's not the last one, you print a comma.

Comment: Thanks MikO but how do I pass through the list of strings from a servlet to the jsp?

Comment: charilaos13 see edit. And that's for sure the code of @BalusC is more complete and is the one you should use, obviously it's a bit more complex as well...

Comment: HI MiKO do you know how can I see the previous Answer of @BalusC because it doesn't show here anymore?

Comment: I don't know, maybe @BalusC has deleted his answer... anyway see EDIT 2 and you can see an improved version of the code that doesn't print the last comma. I don't know if it's the same that BalusC code, but it works! btw if you consider that my answer is useful please upvote it ;)